# ReactiveUI async freezes

Tags: c#, mvvm, avalonia

I am making some Avalonia MVVM app.
When the 'Log In' button is pressed, it looks in the database to see if the account matches, and this operation takes about 1 second. So in order to not freeze the UI for one second, I used await/async :

*Login Command:*

```
  private async Task loginCommand()
  {
      //see if it exists in db
      using (var dbcontext = new DatabaseContext())
      {
          var user = await dbcontext.Credentials.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == this.Email);
          if (user == null)
          {
              //email not found
              await ShowErrorEmail();
              return;
          }
          if (user.Password != this.Password)
          {
              //inccorect password    
              await ShowErrorPassword();
              return;
          }
          //good to go
      }
  }
```

*Command definition :*

```
 var isInputValid = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Email, x => x.Password,
     (email, password) => (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password)
     && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email)));
     
 LoginCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(loginCommand , isInputValid);
```

I debugged and found out that **FirstOrDefaultAsync()** takes about 1 second, but I awaited it so I have no idea why the UI freezes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some database providers, such as SQLite, do not actually support async operations, so all the `...Async()` calls are actually synchronous.
If you're using such database provider, as a workaround you could wrap each call in a `Task.Run()`.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that it isn't the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` that's blocking but the call to `dbcontext.Credentials`. If you want to test that, wrap that in its own `Task.Run`. That way it's all on a separate thread, not just the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` bit.